# tableau custom sql pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot, tableau-api

I have a SQL Server data source that I cannot change the structure of. 
I have started pivoting the data with CustomSQL query below, but I need to modify the query so that when iterations 3, 4 ,5 ...n data are added to the source in the future, it automatically includes it in the pivoted data. I don't want to have to keep updating the query. Any ideas?

### KPI Name   Iteration 1     Iteration 2

a          1               2
b          50              51

```
Select [KPI]
, 'Iteration1' as [Iteration]
, [Iteration1] as [Count]
From [MC_KPI]
Union ALL

Select [KPI]
, 'Iteration2' as [Iteration]
, [Iteration2] as [Count]
From [KPI]
```

Now I have this

### KPI Name   Iteration 1     Iteration 2

a          1               1
a          2               2
b          1              50
b          2              51

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is called "unpivot" in SQL Server.  You can see the description here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

If you want to be able to add iterations without having to modify something in tableau, you can create a view in SQL that does unpivot and just do "select * from view" in tableau.  This would give you the chance to change the view under the covers from tableau and have things continue to work (since the unpivot output is just a property bag and the columns are not really changing as you add properties into the output)

Comment: This answer will work if the author has rights to create a SQL view, which is unclear.

Comment: There's no magic way to unpivot columns to rows in SQL without updating some query or view at some point.